# How to Disable asp.net image using CSS

Tags: javascript, css, image

I have asp.net image which has onclick event .
Now I want to disable this image using CSS. (I want to disable its onclick event)

Comment: try display:none in css

Comment: try to cover that image with a transparent image.

Comment: If you use JS to add `onclick` event, use JS as well to remove it.

Comment: Please show a minimal sample of your code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable image(don't want to show image) then use "display: none" for that particular Id or class.
If you  want to remove link of the image use:
   pointer-events: none;
   cursor: default;

Second thing is, if u have control in the js file, just write 'return false' for that onclick event..

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the image by doing this. Please try this

```
img{ 
 pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: You should mention the browser compatibility of this CSS attribute.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable image

```
display:none;
```

and if u want to disable just click event , u can't do from css. You have to edit your base code where it reside.

Comment: Incorrect. You **can** do it with CSS. use `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: @Raptor  thank. learned new stuff. Though it's not useful to undo js click event as it removes few more stuffs. It simply stops every event for the same.

But it's nice to stop non-techie people from copying stuffs.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS to alter the behavior of JavaScript is not possible. CSS is for styling HTML elements, JavaScript is for handling the behavior of events and the site. CSS and JavaScript are two very different things.
one thing you can do is, you can add transparent layer over the image. But for that also you have to add some changes in html.
only css its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS its not possible to achieve the Javascript functionality. but yes at the time of when you are firing onClick event from asp.net you can make this image function to void. Which means after your onClick event change the Onclick event text of image.

Or if you want to hide the image you can set display:none property from css.